# How to use aggregate functions with where conditions or find in mongoosejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a review schema as following:-

```
const reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    product:{
        type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'products',
        required:false,
        default:null
    },
    user:{
        type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'users',
        required:false,
        default:null
    },
    // status:{
    //     type:String,
    //     required:true,
    //     enum:['pending','approved','rejected'],
    //     default:"pending"
    // },
    rating:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },
    review:{
        type:String,
        required:false
    }
},{timestamps:true});
```

I want get average rating for a specific product so far i am able to get only average rating for the whole schema like this

```
Review.aggregate([
            {
               "$group": {
                  "_id": null,
                  
                  "rating": {
                     "$avg": "$rating"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
        );
```

I am kinda new to mongodb environment , coming from sql background . I tried searching but couldn't find anything relative to this .

P.s:- I also tried binding aggregate after find method . It doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In aggregate you use `$match` pipeline for conditions.

First use `$match` to find product and then use group to calculate average.

```
{
    { $match: { product: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('mongoIdForProductDoc') } },
    {
       $group: { ... your avg calculation }
    },
}
```